# How to load all modules in directory and get class from module

Tags: python, module

I use python 2.7.
I need to load all modules in directory. Some modules stored in directory, some in subdirectory.
Structure

```
dir
   |
   Tool1
   |    |
   |   __init.pyc__
   |   tool1.pyc
   Tool2
   |    |
   |   __init.pyc__
   |   tool2.pyc
   tool3.pyc
   tool4.pyc
```

Each tool contains class with Run method. I can load tool with import then see **dict**.keys()
it looks like:

```
['__all__', '__builtins__', 'glob', '__file__', 'traceback', 'GlobalTool', 'run_me', '__package__', 'sys', '__path__', 'Tool1', 'time', '__name__', 'csv', 'os', '__doc__']
```

Tool1 - is class name.
Each class has attribute __VERSION.
How I can load all modules from directory and extract classes from them and print all modules __VERSTION attribute ?

Additional code info:
Tool1.py:

```
import sys, os, csv
from time import time
import traceback
from core.global_tool import GlobalTool

class ParseFiXEDVALUES(GlobalTool):
    _tool_name = 'FIED_VALUES'
    _VERSION = '0.1'

    def run(self):
        """Main function"""
        start_time = time()
        cur = self.db.cursor()
        pass
```

MyLoad Tool:

```
import os
import sys
mods_dir = '/home/test/multitool'
mods = {}
sys.path.append(mods_dir)

for module in os.listdir(mods_dir):
 if '.py' in module and '.pyc' not in module:
     current = module.replace('.py', '')
     modules[current] = __import__(current)
```

Currently it shows all pyc or py files, but require directories and class routines

Comment: can you show ur snippet or ur trial code ?

Comment: [link]http://ge.tt/3PU90Tr1

Comment: what is that link for i don't wanna click, could you post in ur question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do, is check, if the `module` is a directory with a `__init__.py` file in it:

```
import os
import sys
import importlib
import inspect
import logging

def load_module(module_path, filename):
    """ returns the module if filename is a module else None """
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        module = filename[:-3]
    elif os.path.exists(os.path.join(module_path, filename, '__init__.py')):
        module = filename
    else:
        return None
    try:
        return importlib.import_module(module)
    except:
        logging.exception('Loading %s failed.' % module)
        return None

class PluginManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.modules = {}
        self.classes = {}

    def add_path(self, module_path):
        sys.path.append(module_path)
        for filename in os.listdir(module_path):
            module = load_module(module_path, filename)
            if module:
                self.modules[module.__name__] = module
                self._extract_classes(module)
        sys.path.remove(module_path)

    def _extract_classes(self, module):
        for name in dir(module):
            obj = getattr(module, name)
            if inspect.isclass(obj):
                if hasattr(obj, '_VERSION'):
                    version = getattr(obj, '_VERSION')
                    logging.info("Found %s.%s %s" % (module.__name__, name, version))
                    self.classes[name] = obj

logging.getLogger().level = logging.INFO
plugins = PluginManager()
plugins.add_path('/home/test/multitool')
```

Comment: Code iterates all modules but, do not extract classes.

Comment: I added print module,module_path,filename. Also I modify a little bit load module. I added `code    elif filename.endswith('.pyc'):
    module = filename[:-4] ` to load pyc. Load funtion goes throght and return all pyc and py modules, but classes are not extracted. Still looking how to fix this.

Comment: shame on me. incorrect version spelling was in module